# Why is this array just picking random numbers?

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a really basic program that allows a user to cycle through images, with a set of buttons, and the major problem I'm having with it, is that it appears to just be selecting random points in the array. For example, the array starts at 1, and yet it displays the image that is in the position 0, or let's say I try to cycle backwards through images, if I go from 0 (Which is meant to be position 3), it'll jump back to the image at position 1. I can't make sense of it.

```
var i = 0;

var imageArr = [];

imageArr[0] = 'img/img_BMW.jpg';
imageArr[1] = 'img/img_Chr.jpg';
imageArr[2] = 'img/img_Mas.jpg';
imageArr[3] = 'img/img_Merc.jpg';

function imageCycle(){
  document.imgCycle.src = imageArr[i];

  if(i < imageArr.length - 1){
    i++
  }
  else{
    i = 0;
  }

  console.log(i);
}

function imagePrev(){
  document.imgCycle.src = imageArr[i];

  if(i == imageArr.length - 1){
    i = 3;
  }
  else{
    i--;
  }
}
```

```html
<img name="imgCycle" width="440" height="250"/>
<ul>
    <li><button type="button" id="back-Btn" onclick="imagePrev();">Back</button></li>
    <li><button type="button" id="forward-Btn" onclick="imageCycle();">Forward</button></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the `src` before the value gets incremented.

Try this

```js
var i = 0;

var imageArr = [];

imageArr[0] = 'img/img_BMW.jpg';
imageArr[1] = 'img/img_Chr.jpg';
imageArr[2] = 'img/img_Mas.jpg';
imageArr[3] = 'img/img_Merc.jpg';

function imageCycle(){

  

  if(i < imageArr.length - 1){
    i++
  }
  else{
    i = 0;
  }
document.imgCycle.src = imageArr[i];
  console.log(i);
}

function imagePrev(){
  

  if(i == imageArr.length - 1){
    i = 3;
  }
  else{
    i--;
  }
  document.imgCycle.src = imageArr[i];
  console.log(i);
}
```

```html
<img name="imgCycle" width="440" height="250"/>
<ul>
    <li><button type="button" id="back-Btn" onclick="imagePrev();">Back</button></li>
    <li><button type="button" id="forward-Btn" onclick="imageCycle();">Forward</button></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Worked! Thank you so much.

Comment: Just an FYI, but if you hit back the number gets set to -1.

Answer (score 2):

You could add a method to go to the next index you want and have this function ensure that the index doesn't go out of bounds.

As a side note, binding the event handlers like you did through the `onclick` attribute is not really the preferred way of doing this anymore. Try using `addEventListener` instead.

```js
var i = 0;

// Use some actuale images so we can see what happens in the DOM.
var imageArr = [
  '//placehold.it/300/200/?text=1',
  '//placehold.it/300/200/?text=2',
  '//placehold.it/300/200/?text=3',
  '//placehold.it/300/200/?text=4'
];

/**
 * A method to alter the index. Pass 1 to go to the next slide and -1 to go to 
 * the previous slide. It will make sure the index is never out of bounds.
 */
function getNextIndex(index, modifier) {
  // Add the modifier to the index.
  index = index + modifier;
  // Check if the index is less than zero, this is unvalid and we will reset the index
  // to the last item in the image array. When the index is more than 0, check if it exceeds
  // the index for the last item in the array. In this case reset it to 0 so we go back to 
  // the first image.
  if (index < 0) {
    index = imageArr.length - 1;
  } else if (index >= imageArr.length) {
    index = 0;
  }
  
  return index;
}

function updateImage(index) {
  document.imgCycle.src = imageArr[index];
}

function goToNextImage() {
  i = getNextIndex(i, 1);
  updateImage(i);
}

function goToPreviousImage() {
  i = getNextIndex(i, -1);
  updateImage(i);
}

updateImage(0);
```

```html
<img name="imgCycle" width="440" height="250"/>
<ul>
    <li><button type="button" id="back-Btn" onclick="goToPreviousImage();">Back</button></li>
    <li><button type="button" id="forward-Btn" onclick="goToNextImage();">Forward</button></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: While this does the job, you may want to add an explanation of what you changed and why :)

Comment: I was getting around to that :-)

Answer (score 1):

So the person above me (@Syed) already answered the main issue but I want to point out another issue:

your *imagePrev() function*: It checks if **i** is equal to the array length minus 1, and if it does - you make **i** become *3*.
In your case, it will make the picture be stuck on the last one, and otherwise go back (until **i** reaches -1 and causes issues)

Try this instead:

```
function imagePrev() {

  if (i == 0) {
    i = imageArr.length - 1;
  }
  else {
    i--;
  }
  document.imgCycle.src = imageArr[i];
  console.log(i);
}
```

Cheers

Comment: Oh, didn't pick that up. Thank you!